# AuthGuard Not Working Well in Angular 4

Tags: angular, authentication, angular-services, angular-http

I need help since I have a problem accessing a certain page in my application.
First, you need to login to the app before you can see the dashboard. The problem is that I can't access the dashboard when I put in the `app-routing.module.ts` the `canActivate: [AuthGuard]` in the `DashboardComponent` but when I remove it I can access the dashboard.  Maybe there's a problem on my dashboard.component.ts. Or something else?

> signin.component.ts

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin',
  templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signin.component.css']
})
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, 
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSignIn(form: NgForm){
      const email = form.value.email;
      const password = form.value.password;
      this.authService.signinUser(email, password)
      .subscribe(
          data => {
           this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
             alert("yeah");
          },
          error => {
             alert("nooo");
             console.log(error);
          });

  }

}
```

> auth-guard.service.ts

```ts
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  canActivate() {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

> auth.service.ts

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private loggedIn = false;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.loggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  }

  signinUser(email: string, password: string) {  
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http
    .post(
      'http://example/api/auth/login', 
      JSON.stringify({ email, password }), 
      { headers }
      )
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map((res) => {
      if (res.success) {
        localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.auth_token);
        this.loggedIn = true;
      }

      return res.success;
    });

   }

   isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }
}
```

> app-routing.module.ts

```ts
import{ NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { SigninComponent } from './auth/signin/signin.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth-guard.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/signin', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})
    ],

    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

> dashboard.component.ts

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})

@Injectable()
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);

    return this.http
      .get('/dashboard', { headers })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked what value `canActivate()` returns when the router calls it?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer. How can i check it? :)

Comment: `canActivate() { var val = this.authService.isLoggedIn(); console.log('AuthGuard.canActivate', val); return val;
  }`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer. It says AuthGuard.canActivate false

Comment: And you expect `true`? When yes, why?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer. What's the possible problem in this?

Comment: I don't know, you didn't answer my last question yet. So, are you expecting `true`? If yes, why do you expect it to be `true`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer. Yes, It must be true so that would authguard would work

Comment: Inspect your auth.service.ts, when mapping your response to res.success, confirm that you're getting a success response, or at your singin component when you subscribe, check if data is not undefined | null | false

Comment: And @GünterZöchbauer he's navigating after setting `this.loggedIn`. So the `http` request have been resolved.

Comment: @MiguelLattuada I guess you are right, I misinterpreted the code. Then he should check if `if (res.success) { ... }` is executed at all (`res.success` actually is `true`)

Comment: @MiguelLattuada. I put console.log(res) and the response is successful

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer. The response from the api is {message: "Login successful", response: true, token: "ey....

Comment: but is the code inside `if(res.success) { ... }` actually executed. Believing that it is executed is not enough ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer. What should i write?

Comment: You can add `console.log('yes, I'm actually being executed');` inside the if, and check if this is printed ;-) or set a breakpoint inside the `if(){...}` if you're comfortable using a debugger.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer No it doesnt output the yes, im actually being executed

Comment: This are basic debugging skills. You need to ensure that the code actually does what you expect it does ;-) Check if `res.success` is for example the string `'true'` instead of the boolean value `true` or similar (whatever the reason might be that `res.success` isn't evaluated to `true`). I have no way of debugging your from here.